# Keydown Event fires twice

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

On a Windows store App, I have this simple TextBox

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxUser" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="147" Margin="20,0,0,0" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" /
```

That has a KeyDown Event associated with it.

```
        private async void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
           Debug.WriteLine("LA");
        }
    }
```

And the output of this function is:

> LA
> LA

although I press Enter only once, it prints 2 times.
Any reason for that or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You sure you haven't accidentally subscribed to the event more than once?

Comment: Apparently its a bug acording to one of the replies from this post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/734d6c7a-8da2-48c6-9b3d-fa868b4dfb1d/c-textbox-keydown-triggered-twice-in-metro-applications?forum=winappswithcsharp
I used KeyUp event instead and it works now.

Comment: Still happening in UWP TextBox on Windows 10 Creators Update, using e.Handled = true; fixed it for me.

Answer (score 17):

This should only fire the event once, so if it is firing twice I would check a couple of things.

Check that you aren't handling the key down event on a parent control. This could be a panel or the containing window. Events will bubble down through the visual tree. For example a key down on a textbox will also be a keydown on the window containing the textbox.

To stop this happening you can mark the event as handled as below;

```
e.Handled = true;
```

The other thing to check is that you aren't subscribing to the event twice. The XAML will do the same as;

TextBoxUser.KeyDown += TextBox_KeyDown

so check that you don't have this in your code behind.

You can check the sender and e.OriginalSource property to see where the event is being fired from.

Comment: Although your solution is right, I think there is a bug on the KeyDown event!

Comment: Adding `e.Handled = true;` at the end of my handler did the trick. Curious as to why this was happening. I was listening for the KeyUp, not KeyDown, but I assume it's the same situation. The event listener got each KeyUp event twice for some reason. Is this really a bug in the events as mentioned in another answer?

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a ton! Works after we add a condition at the beginning of the Keyup/down event to check if e.handled is true!

Answer (score 6):

This is a known bug in Windows RT.You can handle it by checking the Key RepeatCount `

```
if (e.KeyStatus.RepeatCount == 1)
{
   //Execute code
}
```

Comment: Was this bug fixed in the meanwhile? When targeting w10 1803 I can no longer reproduce this.

Answer (score 4):

I finally realized that there is probably a **bug in the KeyDown event**.

When I set, as @daniellepelley said,

```
e.Handled = true;
```

the event still propagates: other buttons will intercept it, also if they shouldn't.

In my code, I just replaced KeyDown event with KeyUp event and everything works fine (always setting Handled to True value)!

Comment: Replacing KeyDown with KeyUp solved my problem too !

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late, but `e.preventDefault()` worked for me. Especially in React - TypeScript.

```
(e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void onKeyPressEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Handled)
  return;

  {
    //
    // the block of codes to be executed on the key press
    // should added here.
    //
  }
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We've a guide [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be great if you could improve your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue in Xamarin.Android where the keypress event fired twice.

In my case it is because the KeyDown and KeyUp are two separate actions which both call the same event. I only respond to one action as below:

```
    private void KeyPress(object sender, View.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter)
        {
            if (e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down)
            {
                Event();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

i was seeing this issue in javascript, where keydown event handler is fired twice, and was able to fix by using .off().on()

```
$('.text_area').off().on('keydown', function (e) {

// do something

)};
```

what it does is that, it switches off the extra events and the takes the latest keydown action and executes the handler for it

for me only this solution worked well
thanks

Comment: How can this be applied to C#/UWP?