# UWP C# Eliminate double comma from textbox.txt

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a textbox in my app that I would like users to be able to enter a string into and hit enter, which adds that string to a variable and clears the textbox.  They can add multiple strings to the variable via the textbox, each separated by a comma.  But when I add the full record to my csv file it has double commas.  I can't see where they are being added.

**desired result**
1/1/2017,12:00,joe,out,1234,09112,4545,120034

**what I'm getting now**
1/1/2017,12:00,joe,out,1234,,09112,,4545,,120034,,

here's the relevant code:

```
        private void meterNumberBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
            {
                singlescan = meterNumberBox.Text + ",";
                meternumber += singlescan;
                meterNumberBox.Text = "";
                singlescan = "";

            }
        }


        private async void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            action = "out";

            // create record to be added to CSV
            recordline = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + ",";
            recordline += DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
            recordline += ",";
            recordline += checkoutName;
            recordline += ",";
            recordline += action;
            recordline += meternumber;
            recordline += "\r\n";

// then it submits the recordline to the record file.
        // open csv and append record
        StorageFolder appStoragefolder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
        StorageFile appRecordFile = await appStoragefolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists); // if it doesn't exist it will be created
        var stream = await appRecordFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        using (var outputstream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(stream.Size))
        {
            using (var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(outputstream))
            {
                dataWriter.WriteString(recordline);
                await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                await outputstream.FlushAsync();
            }
        }

        stream.Dispose();
```

I think I can eliminate the double commas from the recordline with a .replace() , but I really want to understand what I'm doing wrong to cause the problem.

Thanks for any input!

**Edit:**  After a little more testing, it appears that `enter` is being hit twice each time the keyboard Enter is pressed.  Not sure why.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] it will be impossible to offer a good answer with specific advice. That said, based on what you wrote, it appears everything is fine. You seem to be using a CSV implementation that uses a double-comma to escape a comma (required, since a single comma delimits fields within a row in the file). As long as you use the same CSV implementation to read the file, I'd expect it to correctly decode the escaped commas.

Comment: I've edited my question to show that I'm simply adding a string to a text file, not using any CSV handling methods.

Comment: Also, there is nothing here to prevent the user from pressing Enter while the textbox is empty which would result in an extra comma.  Not necessarily what is happening now, but something to be aware of.

Comment: dazed:  yes, I realized that but decided it wasn't a concern; the app will be running without a keyboard, only using a barcode scanner and the touchscreen buttons.  While they have several ways they can mess up the recordline, I haven't gotten to those issues yet :)

Comment: While testing, are you entering the numbers with a barcode scanner? Could the scanner be passing along an `Enter` after each scan, so when you press `Enter` again it inserts the second comma? (There might be other reasons for the event to happen twice.)

Comment: That's what I thought at first, that somehow the way I have the code is causing it to insert a comma twice - I'm testing this on a desktop, so I know I only hit enter once.  The scanner, I don't know if it only sends one `Enter` after each scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing I needed to search with the phrase "UWP keydown event firing twice" I discovered the answer to my problem.  Based on a blog article and a post here it seems this is a bug in Windows 10 UWP apps.

http://blog.mzikmund.com/2015/12/winrt-keydown-fired-twice-when-enter-is-pressed/

and

[Keydown Event fires twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012948/keydown-event-fires-twice)

I was able to resolve my particular case by adding:

```
if (e.KeyStatus.RepeatCount == 1)
{
   //Execute code
}
```

So my final event handler looks like this:

```
private async void meterNumberBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        if (e.KeyStatus.RepeatCount == 1)
        {
            singlescan = meterNumberBox.Text + ",";
            meternumber += singlescan;
            singlescan = "";
            meterNumberBox.Text = "";
        }
    }

}
```